# Creating Light Sensor

Tags: led, robot

So the situation is like this, I have a project with a budget of $25. I have to build a robot that is capable of connecting a magnet to a tin can autonomously. I also have a vex kit which I can use for free. I need to create a system so that the robot can find the tin can and drive to connect the magnet from up to 3m away with no obstacles between the robot and the tin can. We are provided with an IR beacon that flashes as 10Hz but previous people who have done this experiment have told me that the IR light is almost impossible to detect without aimlessly driving around the arena for a while. We are allowed to use a different detection method if we would prefer.

I want to use visible light and a phototransistor to detect when I am looking at the tin can. I would wrap the tin can with retroreflective tape and have a LED ring light on the robot. The LED light would bounce back and go through a magnifying glass to focus the light on the phototransistor. However, the Vex kit only provides 5V out and the LED light has 15 LEDs which I think makes it require 10.5V to function at full power. Is there a cheap way to power the light without a car battery or is there a way I can cut down on other costs, like removing the need for the tape/magnifying glass?

Comment: From your description, you'd still have an aimless-driving problem with the LED + retroreflector, since reflected light is only detected when the robot's LED array is pointing at the can. The IR beacon ought to be very detectable ten feet away (although a higher frequency than 10 Hz would be better).

Comment: I was going to have the LED mounted on a tower that rotates with a potentiometer at the base. That way the sensor/LED can rotate until it shines at the can and then we will turn towards the target based on how far the potentiometer was rotated. Maybe the reason that the IR doesn't work is due to bad sensors. Is it possible to make/ buy better IR detectors than they might provide in a lab?

Comment: You are provided with some tools. You've mentioned some. I'd like to see more details. Exactly what is allowed "for free" and what are the specs. (The IR beacon, for example. What EXACTLY is it? Does it flash at some rate? What emitter type is it? Etc.) There is way, way too little here. Also, I see you can modify the can. But no specs on what mods would be allowed and what mods would not be. There's a lot missing here. Too many questions, right now, in my mind... too many possible solutions to weed through. I need a narrowing of the problem set. That means spec details.

Comment: This question is very broad.  The description also leaves too many questions open, and would require too much back and forth to clarify.  It's much simpler to close and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A large difficulty to be overcome is the variability of background illumination.
- Another problem is one of dynamic range of detected light intensity.

**Variable background:** As the robot points to different locations, it detects more light (perhaps when pointing toward a window) or less light (perhaps while pointing to a dark corner). Detected light from a beacon or from a retro-reflector may be only a little greater than this background illumination.
 What you want to detect is the difference between **background** and **background + light source.**
Modulation of the light source is a method of overcoming the variable-background problem. The light source is rapidly turned on and off, perhaps 1000 times-per-second. A reasonably fast light detector (a photo transistor) is used to detect the changes from on-to-off. The alternating amplitude of its photo current can be passed through a band-pass filter centered at 1000 Hz to yield an AC signal whose amplitude is proportional to detected light from only the light source, not from the variable background.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE71wW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Dynamic range:** Detected light amplitude may vary greatly with distance. At ten feet distance, detected amplitude will be small, even when optimally pointed at the source. At a few inches distance, detected amplitude will be a great deal larger. A photodetector must cope with this large signal range, yet still be able to measure *small changes* in amplitude. A variable-gain amplifier can help: high gain at large distance, low gain at short distance.

Comment: You miss out the need for bandpass optical filtering (you have to eliminate sunlight and bright lights that might cause the sensor to saturate) and lenses for the phototransistor.

Comment: @JackCreasey Yes, optical filtering can help some. R1 resistance is chosen small enough so that the phototransistor doesn't saturate when pointed at the brightest source (a very close LED, or sunlight, or large ambient light). Yet R1 must be as large as you dare to provide good light sensitivity. I've done 10 ft distance retroreflector with no optical filtering or lenses with one RED LED fairly easily.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I am sorry for unclear information I am new to using stackExchange and I didn't want to make a massive post as I wasn't sure if that was acceptable. Have a good day!